# c, hex representation in big-endian system

Tags: c, hex, endianness

What is result of:

```
int x = 0x00000001;
int y = 0x80000000;
```

in a big-endian system?

My goal is to define an int that has the first (in memory) bit set, regardless of whether it is the most significant one or the least significant one. I know that with little-endian systems, x would satisfy this requirement, but is it still true in a big-endian system?

I'm pretty sure that the following will work in both systems:

```
char c[4] = {0x80, 0, 0, 0};
int x = (int) c;
```

Is that correct? Is there a more elegant method?

(I don't have a big-endian system to experiment on)

Comment: "the first bit set"? What's your definition of "first"? IMHO it is the least significant one, in which case, `0x00000001` is your answer, regardless of the Endian-ness.

Comment: The second method would cast address of the array to int, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the first bit of the first byte its high bit or its low bit?

Comment: ok, my definition of first is first in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
int x = 0;
char* p = (char*)&x;
p[0] = 0x01;
```

---

The above code will set the least significant bit in the lowest-address byte of an `int` variable to 1:

- On a Big-Endian processor, it will set the LS-bit in the MS-byte to 1 (i.e., `x == 0x10000000`).
- On a Little-Endian processor, it will set the LS-bit in the LS-byte to 1 (i.e., `x == 0x00000001`).

---

Having said that, what is your definition of "the first bit"? IMHO it is simply the least significant one, in which case, `int x = 0x00000001` is the answer regardless of the Endianness of your processor!!

---

The following terminology might help you to understand a little better:

- Set the least significant bit in an 8-bit byte: 0x01
- Set the most significant bit in an 8-bit byte: 0x80
- Set the least significant byte in a 4-byte integer: 0x000000FF
- Set the most significant byte in a 4-byte integer: 0xFF000000
- Set the lowest-address byte in a 4-byte integer on a LE processor: 0x000000FF
- Set the lowest-address byte in a 4-byte integer on a BE processor: 0xFF000000
- Set the highest-address byte in a 4-byte integer on a LE processor: 0xFF000000
- Set the highest-address byte in a 4-byte integer on a BE processor: 0x000000FF

Comment: my definition of "first" is with regard to memory position.

Comment: @giladrv: A bit does not have a memory position, as the minimal unit for a memory address is *byte*. In any case, If you want to set least significant bit in the lowest-address byte, then the solution above should work.

Comment: I want to right shift that bit on the entire int, i.e.: 100000... >> 01000... >> 00100... (that's the context in which I refer to first bit, i.e. left most bit)

Comment: @giladrv: Right-shift (or any other arithmetic operation for that matter) works the same, regardless of the Endianness. You do not need to concern yourself on how to construct integer values so that the operation will be executed correctly!!!

Comment: I don't mean to upset you, but it is still unclear to me. So the left most bit in a byte, is always the most significant one? i.e. it will be set by assigning 0x80 to that byte? Is that true? And is that independent on Endianness?

Comment: @giladrv: 1. You are not upsetting me. 2. Please see updated answer, I have added some terminology that might help you to understand a little better.

Comment: Great, thanks! For future references, I'll rephrase the answer as - "(1) MostSignificantByte is set with 0xFF000000 regardless of Endianness; (2) LeftMostBit = MostSignificantBit, regardless of Endianness."

Comment: @giladrv: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer by clickking on the V next to it if it works out for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try unions

```
union foo
{
  char array[8];
  int64_t num;
};
```